# Set user as online in asp.net membership

Tags: c#, asp.net

When a user sets the option (remember me) and closes the browser and then opens the site again he does not appear listed with the on-line members.

How can I set a user to `on-line` after the user reopens the site again?

I am using this code `Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline();` but it returns 0 on-line

Comment: Have you set the [userIsOnlineTimeWindow property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.userisonlinetimewindow.aspx) in your web.config?

Comment: @jadarnel27 - doubt they want the user to be shown as online when they aren't for weeks at a time.

Comment: @MystereMan I wasn't recommending they set it to a large number. I was just wondering if they had it set to a very small number by mistake (like 1). In which case, I could see them ending up with 0 users online pretty frequently. And the OP might not know that this setting factors in to the results of the call to GetNumberOfUsersOnline().  Are you picking up what I'm putting down, yo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "sets the option" you mean sets the "remember me" flag.  The reason for this is that this just sets a persistent cookie on the users computer.  They are not "logged in" again afterwards.  Thus, the Membership login never occurs again.

You need to perform some membership activity that has a "userIsOnline" flag, such as calling Membership.GetUser(username, true) to set the userIsOnline.

Comment: thank you so so much, it works fine Membership.GetUser(username, true) to set user as on-line

Answer (score 0):

As an **alternative**, if you want to track users online, you could look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), see some [tutorials here](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

There's a post with a similar question here [SignalR for tracking online users and chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654588/signalr-for-tracking-online-users-and-chat).

and here [signalR tracking connected users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203141/signalr-tracking-connected-users)