# Send message to sender of SignalR request

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Can you with SignalR send information the client who has send the request? Here I've quickly draw the current situation with paint:

[image]

The client send a SignalR request to the server with

```
meldingenHub.server.vote();
```

and the server send a message back to **all** the clients with

```
Clients.All.SendOke();
```

The situation I will have is that only the sender of that request, receive the message I send form the server. All the other clients don't receive that message. Is there something I can use like this:

```
Clients.Sender.SendOke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is send the connection id of the sender to the hub and then use `Clients.Client(connId).broadcastMessage(....)` see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872589/call-specific-client-from-signalr) other answer for an example.

Answer (score 2):

When the Server method is invoked, there is a `Context` object populated with the details of who called the method. There is a property in here called `ConnectionId` which has the identifier of the caller.

So to invoke a method only on the sender's client, simply call:

`await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("ClientMetodName");`